# I get a StackOverFlowException on this code because my JVM doesn't support tail call optimizaion, right?

Tags: java, tail-recursion, stack-overflow, tail-call-optimization

I get a `StackOverflowException` on this Java method:

```
private static final Integer[] populate(final Integer[] array, final int length, final int current) {

    if (current == length) {
        return array;
    } else {
        array[current] = TR.random.nextInt();
        System.out.println(array[current]);
        return populate(array, length, current + 1);
    }
}
```

I'm playing with tail call recursion so I guess this is what happens when the JVM doesn't short circuit the stack right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No JVM that I'm aware of supports tail call optimization.  This is not an oversight.  Apparently this optimization has significant consequences for Java reflection and Java security managers.

References:

- ["Tail calls in the VM"](http://blogs.oracle.com/jrose/entry/tail_calls_in_the_vm) by John Rose @ Oracle.
- [Bug 4726340 - RFE: Tail Call Optimization](http://bugs.oracle.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4726340)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Tail Call Optimization is not currently supported by the JVM because of the security model and the need to always have a stack trace available, this example could easily be rewritten using iteration though.

Comment: Hi, of course it can be easily expressed with a for loop... it's an exercise after all ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found a [reference of tail recursion](http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html) in java, therefore I would check this, (later when I've time).

Although it would be extremly ineffiecent for your use case.

Comment: I don't think the document adds much... the reference to tail recursion doesn't mention whether the stack references are optimized away

Answer (score 1):

Plain Java doesn't have tail call optimization, AFAIK. Scala does have a somewhat limited implementation of it: http://fupeg.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-in-scala.html